# addon domain not working on http cloudflare

Tags: http, cpanel, cloudflare

I've set up a parked domain and set it's nameservers to cloudflare nameservers. but I have a strange problem. I can access the parked domain only with https (e.g. https://domain.xyz).
If I access it using http it will redirect to defaultwebpage.cgi. but if I access one of the files or folders or pages (e.g. http://domain.xyz/test) the page will load without any problems. the problem only exists on the homepage (e.g. http://domain.xyz).
the cloudflare is using flexible setting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not cloudflare issues, Might be there is an issues with your local end, Please try to clear your browser cache and try again. OR try to check your domain through proxy sites.

Comment: You could also try to access your website in a private window in your browser. Also you could clear all the caches from cloudflare and wait like 30 seconds to be sure that all the cache was deleted. Then try again

Answer (score 0):

Did you create any Page Rules in Cloudflare? I understand that you use a Cloudflare Flexible SSL certificate. In order to redirect http traffic (with our without www) to https traffic you need to add a Page Rule in Cloudflare. Did you do that?

Create a page rule like this in Cloudflare:

```
http://*.domain.xyz/* that redirects to https://www.domain.xyz/$1
```

Comment: I did what you said. and I still have the same problem